# Tizen error code 1102 using "Debug as"

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I don't know what to do anymore, search everywhere for the possible cause of the error, and so far nothing.

Every time i try to lauch my app into the device using the Debug As (F11), it simple fails. If i do it in normal mode, no problem occours but i need the console.log to be avaible. There is other way to do it? How can i fix the debug problem?

```
Setting the debugging URL... > Fail
Error occurred at the below step.
 `Setting the debugging URL...`
 (Return Code:1102)Cannot read response content.
```

---

```
Launching the Tizen application...
# If you want to see the detailed information,
# please set the logging level to DEBUG in Preferences and check the log file in 'C:\tizen-wearable-sdk-data\ide\logs/ide-20150128_125226.log'.

[Initializing the launch environment...]
    RDS: Off
    Target information: SM-R750B
    Application information: Id(tJEO2H9vrX.BatimentoCardaco), Package Name(tJEO2H9vrX), Project Name(BatimentoCardiaco)
[Transferring the package...]
    Transferred the package: C:\Users\fav\workspace-wear\BatimentoCardiaco\BatimentoCardiaco.wgt -> /opt/usr/apps/tmp
[Stopping running application...]
[Uninstalling the package...]
start process (uninstall)

end process (ok)
spend time for pkgcmd is [1292]ms
cmd_ret:0
    Uninstalled the package: Id(tJEO2H9vrX.BatimentoCardaco)
[Installing the package...]
path is /opt/usr/apps/tmp/BatimentoCardiaco.wgt
start process (install)
..........
icon_path : /opt/usr/apps/tJEO2H9vrX/shared/res/tJEO2H9vrX.BatimentoCardaco.png
.......
end process (ok)
spend time for pkgcmd is [7358]ms
cmd_ret:0
    Installed the package: Id(tJEO2H9vrX), Version(1.0.0)
[Running the application...]
[Setting the debugging port...]
    Forwarded port: local(48254) -> remote(48254)
[Setting the debugging URL...]
Unexpected stop progress...
(17.874 sec)
```

**The log "C:\tizen-wearable-sdk-data\ide\logs/ide-20150128_125226.log" file is empty**

**FYI, i'm using:**

- Windows 8.1
- Tizen SDK for Wearable - Version: 1.0.0 - Build id: 20140905-2017
- Galaxy Gear S (SM-R750B / SM-R750BZWAZTO)

[]'s

Comment: But your app is running on the device, just the debugger is missing?

Comment: Are you running a firewall? You might need to create an exception for the IDE. I've seen some problems with 8.1 at a hackathon we were at a few months ago.

Comment: Yes, there is a firewall active, i don't know how that's a problem.. but... i can't "deal" with that (company) hahaha.

--- 

BTW, i just created another project in another workspace and i can run as debug, maybe the project/workspace got corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting this error is because for wearables device, the web inspector has been disabled inside webkit. Hence, "Debug" as will not work and it shows Error 1102.

But you can debug your web app on the wearable emulator, there you'd not face this error.